# Join table id not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I already joined two table and view data.
Here is my controller:

```
$data = DB::table('classrooms')
        ->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')->get();
        return View::make('std_classes')->with('data',$data);
```

And Here is my view

```
<h4><a href="{{ URL::to('class/'.$data->id) }}">{{$data->class_name}}</a></h4>
                    <h5>Section:{{$data->section}} </h5>
```

It's working nice. But my problem is in my url `{{ URL::to('class/'.$data->id) }}` i need here classroom id. But it's print joinclass id.
How can i solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually `select` them out as you've 2 fields with the same name `id`.

```
$data = DB::table('classrooms')
    ->select('classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'joinclass.*')
    ->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')->get();
    return View::make('std_classes')->with('data',$data);
```

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$class_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject11\resources\views\std_classes.blade.php) classrooms table id and joinclass table id is not same in my table.

Comment: ->select('classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*'), try this